# How to fix non-numeric values error or find such non-numeric values in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, numberformatter

I'm adding localisation to currencies, dates, and numbers in a project I'm continuously developing. However, when added number formatting using PHP's `NumberFormatter` class, I get `Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in...`.

This supposedly means that a non-numeric value was stored in my database. I'm not sure how this is possible since the respective column is `decimal(11,20`) but there's no other explanation I can find. I must note that the `quantity` column used to be VARCHAR until a few years ago, when I switched it to DECIMAL, but I haven't seen any errors or warnings before this.

Here's the PHP code that throws the error:

```
$num = new NumberFormatter('en_UK', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
...
$units_quantity = $num->format($units_row['units_sum']);
...

if(isset($units_total[$year][$units_unit])) {
    $units_total[$year][$units_unit] += $units_quantity; /* THIS LINE */
}
else {
    $units_total[$year][$units_unit] = $units_quantity;
}
```

If I amend the PHP code above by casting the number as `floatval` like so:

```
 $units_total[$year][$units_unit] += floatval($units_quantity);
```

I still get two non-numeric value warnings – but now the calculations are incorrect. There are a total of thirteen warnings before the change.

To try and find the non-numeric value in MySQLL, I tried these queries, both returning zero rows:

```
SELECT projectID, projectName, quantity FROM project_data WHERE quantity REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]';

SELECT projectID, projectName, quantity FROM project_data WHERE quantity REGEXP '^[^0-9]+$';
```

I hope you can point me in the right direction. Let me know if I can provide any additional details.

Comment: You shouldn't format numbers before calculations. WHICH is giving you a non-numeric value

Comment: _"This supposedly means that a non-numeric value was stored in my database."_ - no, it doesn't. After all, you are not getting the error from the line where you are formatting the value you are getting from the database - you are getting it from the line, where you are trying to add this value to something else. The number formater you are using, is inserting thousands separators - a numeric input value like `1234`, will get you the _string_ value `1,234`- and that is not a format PHP can do calculations with.

Comment: I didn't know PHP can't calculate formatted numbers.

Comment: Well why would you expect it to? Formatting is a way of making a number more readable to humans (and humans in different regions and cultures have different expectations of how a number should be formatted!). At that point it ceases to be a number and becomes a piece of text, for presentation purposes. Computers can calculate on raw numbers, not on _visual representations_ of those numbers. It's the same with dates - think how many ways there are to format a date. But computers will store and process them internally as numeric timestamps which no human would be able to interpret by reading it.

Comment: @ADyson, thanks. This is perfectly logical. My misunderstanding must stem from my being a linguist dabbling in coding, not a programmer who received institutional training in computing. I'll add this piece of knowledge to my collection of other pieces.